# Find values on two colums on different sheets that don't match

Tags: excel, formula

I have two worksheets, both have a column called part number. I need to find only the rows from both sheets that are unique. So if sheet one has:

```
part number
------------
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

and sheet 2 has:

```
part number
------------
abc
def
ghi
zzz
```

I need the results to be:

```
jkl
zzz
```

Answer (score 0):

A formula of this kind in each sheet (copied down to suit) should identify uniques with `#N/A`:

`=MATCH(A2,Sheet4!A:A,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You could copy both lists to be in the same column and then advanced filter for unique values

Answer (score 0):

in sheet #3 column A paste the following

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!$A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,1,FALSE)),Sheet2!$A1,"")
```

and in sheet #3 column B

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,1,FALSE)),Sheet1!$A1,"")
```

that will list values from sheet1 not found in sheet2 and vice versa.

hope that helps